# Updating a column with random integers, but keep getting ERROR (code 1064)

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I have a code that should be able to generate unique random numbers, but once I run it gives me this error code:

> (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'varbinary , newid () ) ), 0 )WHERE simplefocusstatistic_id = 3
>   AND Player_id = N' at line 1")

```
sql= " UPDATE simplefocusstatistic_studentanswers SET Player_id = ROUND(1000 *RAND( convert ( varbinary , newid () ) ), 0 ) WHERE simplefocusstatistic_id = 3 AND Player_id = NULL  "
```

Comment: It looks like you have your arguments swapped for [convert](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert)

Comment: It should be `CONVERT(newid(), varbinary)`.

Comment: Note that Python doesn't usually require you to convert datatypes explicitly. If a function needs a numeric argument, it will convert a string automatically.

Comment: @Barmar thank you for the help. I changed my code as you suggested but the same error message reoccurs. This is the new code 
` sql= " UPDATE simplefocusstatistic_studentanswers SET Player_id` `=ROUND(1000 *RAND( convert ( newid (), varbinary ), 0 ) WHERE` `simplefocusstatistic_id = 3 AND Player_id = NULL `

Error code:
1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'varbinary ), 0 )WHERE simplefocusstatistic_id = 3 AND Player_id = NULL' at line 1")

Comment: See the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert). `VARBINARY` is not one of the types that you can use with the `CONVERT()` function.

Comment: I made a mistake in my earlier comment, I meant that MySQL doesn't require you to convert types explicitly. Just use `newid()` instead of `CONVERT(newid(), varbinary)`.

Comment: @Barmar thank you for the tips.